# Instantiating and configuring loggers in Enterprise Library 5.0 + Silverlight

Tags: silverlight, enterprise-library

I'm using Enterprise Library 5.0, Logging block, in a Silverlight project.
In the project I want to be able to instantiate a logger, I believe the right class is LogWriterImpl.
And I also wanted to be able to configure this LogWriterImpl with Xml configuration, so in the end I want something like this:

```
public class LoggerFactory
{
    public LoggerWriter Create(string xmlFilePath)
    {
        // Load configuration from xmlFilePath
        ???

        // Read the configuration and create the parameters for the LogWritterImpl
        ???

        // In Silverlight there are several constructors for the LogWritterImpl class
        // which one to use? which arguments to use?
        var logger = new LogWritterImpl( /* which parameters go here? */ );

        return logger;
    }
}
```

Can anyone help me to fill in the blanks?

Thank you for your time!

Answer (score 0):

See this walkthrough:
http://channel9.msdn.com/posts/Enterprise-Library-for-Silverlight-Logging-demo

Source code of the demo is [here](http://entlib.codeplex.com/releases/view/63549).

Also, see [this chapter](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh852706%28v=pandp.51%29) of the Developer's Guide.